# How can I emulate Paint.NET's 'recolor' tool with ImageMagick?

Tags: images, colors, imagemagick

I'd like to recolor one shade of blue to another in an image (for which I also have vector copies).  In Paint.NET, I could pick up the color in my source image, choose a replacement color in the color picker, and broadly stroke the image until it's entirely recolored.  Intermittent shades of the color (as they're antialiased) are similarly recolored.

I'm trying to achieve the same effect with ImageMagick, but I can't make heads or tails of [IM's documentation on recoloring](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#color_lut).  I'd like to call something like

```
convert original.png -recolor-from #ff0000 -recolor-to ##00ff00 recolored.png
```

I've tried

```
convert original.png +level-colors '#172871,#092072' recolored.png
```

[without success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NBdO.jpg) ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSacf.jpg)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
convert original.png -fuzz 15% -fill '#00ff00' -opaque '#ff0000' recolored.png
```

the larger the fuzz factor, the more similar colours will match. (Note the order of the parameters: `fill` is the to-colour but is first). See the ImageMagick [replace](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace) basics page.

Comment: `convert -size 100x100 canvas:#ff0000 original.png; convert original.png -fuzz 15% -fill '#00ff00' -opaque '#ff0000' recolored.png` This solution doesn't give a pure green fill in `recolored.png`.

Comment: What are you seeing? It works as expected for me, on Linux ImageMagick 6.9.2-7.

Comment: Hmm, nevermind – it looks like there's some funky behavior going on with OS X's digital color meter. Querying IM about the value of a pixel shows it's pure: `convert recolored.png txt:- | head -n 10`.